# Remove symbols from link '($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])).'

Tags: php

Currently using this code:

```
str_replace(".php","",basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
```

and it outputs like this:

Rusko%20-%20Skanker.mp3&sort=1

i need it to display so: Rusko - Skanker

Comment: Try a regular expression to get rid of the url-coded characters.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `urldecode()`:

```
urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the following URL:

script.php?file=Rusko%20-%20Sanker.mp3&sort=1

Then, to get the result you are looking for, you would want:

```
echo htmlentities( urldecode( str_replace( '.mp3', '', $_GET['file'] ) ), ENT_QUOTES );
```

The other answers aren't *quite* complete because they will include the entire URL in the output. You seem to be looking for just one query string parameter.

**Note:** htmlentities() is VERY important in this case to protect your website and users. Printing any user submitted data on a page without properly sanitizing it first allows for code injection.